# gdal_polygonize: Create polygons for each grid regardless of value

Tags: raster, gdal

I'm using glad_polygonise to convert an ASCII file to MapInfo TAB. This is working nicely but it's combining the same values together into a single polygon so rather than have individual grids per ASCII cell I'm getting combined polygons.

Is there a way to stop this and return polygons for each and every ASCII grid cell regardless of value?

Many thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in QGIS which does this called "Raster pixels to polygons", search for it in the toolbox menu.

If you have to use GDAL, consider creating a raster which has unique values for each pixel, with Python for example: `np.arange(ys*xs).reshape(ys,xs)`

Comment: Hi Rutger, many thanks for this and apologies for the delay. Christmas and New year revelry. I'll test this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with the "Create Grid" tool in QGIS 3. This gives you the freedom to decide on the data extent and spacing of individual polygons.

[image]